# Cannot list details data in jQuery Datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatable, datatables

I followed [jQuery Datatable - Sliding child rows](https://datatables.net/blog/2014-10-02) example (just look at "Complete code" section on that page) in my ASP.NET MVC project and I could listed master & static details data properly. However, when I want to retrieve details data dynamically via AJAX, I cannot listed them properly due to an error **TypeError: table.fnOpen is not a function**. There is a solution changing **D**ataTable to **d**ataTable, but in this case I encounter another errors. The problem is exactly on the click & format method and I think I made a mistake for some definition. Could you please have a look at and clarify me about where the mistake is? Thanks in advance...

```
function format(d) {
    return '<div class="slider">' +
    '<table style="width:100%">' +
      '<tr>' +
            '<th>Name</th>' +
            '<th>Surname</th> ' +
            '<th>Number</th>' +
        '</tr>' +
        '<tr>' +
            '<td>' + d.StudentName + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + d.StudentSurname + '</td> ' +
            '<td>' + d.StudentNumber + '</td>' +
        '</tr>' +
    '</table>'
    '</div>';
}


$(document).ready(function () {

    var table;
    table = $('#dtbLabGroup')
        .DataTable(

        //code omitted for brevity

        "columns": [
                    {
                        "class": 'details-control',
                        "orderable": false,
                        "data": null,
                        "defaultContent": ''
                    },
                    { "name": "Lab" },
                    { "name": "Schedule" },
                    { "name": "Term" },
                    { "name": "Status" }
        ],          
        "order": [[1, 'asc']],
    });


    // Add event listener for opening and closing details
    $('#dtbLabGroup tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {

        // !!! There might be a problem regarding to these 3 parameters
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = table.row(tr);            
        var nTr = $(this).parents('tr')[0];
        //

        if (row.child.isShown()) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            $('div.slider', row.child()).slideUp(function () {
                row.child.hide();
                tr.removeClass('shown');
            });
        }
        else {
            // Open this row
            row.child(format(row.data()), 'no-padding').show();
            tr.addClass('shown');

            $('div.slider', row.child()).slideDown();

            // !!! There is PROBABLY a problem
            // !!! I added the following code for retrieving data via AJAX call. 
            var id = 8; //used static id for testing
            $.get("GetStudents?id=" + id, function (students) {
                table.fnOpen(nTr, students, 'details');
            });
        }
    }); 

});
```

**Update I:** Here is the modified format() method below:

```
function format(d) {
    var htmlResult = '<div class="slider">' +
    '<table style="width:100%">' +
      '<tr>' +
            '<th>Name</th>' +
            '<th>Surname</th> ' +
            '<th>Number</th>' +
        '</tr>';

       $.each(d, function (i, d) {
           htmlResult += '<tr><td>' + d[i].StudentName + '</td><td>' + d[i].StudentSurname + '</td><td>' + d[i].StudentNumber + '</td></tr>';
       });

    htmlResult += '</table>' +
    '</div>';
    return htmlResult;
}
```

Comment: `fnOpen` is v1.9 syntax, which is why changing `Datatables` to `datatables` is a solution.  The example you've linked to doesn't use `fnOpen` at all - so I wonder why you've used it?  see [here](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/22371/datatables-1-10-0-fnopen-otable-columns-contradictory-behaviour)

Comment: Because I have to use AJAX call to load data and there is **fnOpen** method in the example I found. Is there a better example without **fnOpen**? Thanks...

Comment: Are you trying to use fnOpen to add a new row?

Comment: No, I use v1.10 and I know I should not use fnOpen. The only think I need a **format(row.child);** method (having an AJAX call) that is callked from **// Open this row** section. Any example usage of it please? Thanks a lot...

Comment: I still don't understand what you're trying to use `fnOpen` for...

Comment: Just look at // Open this row section and forget fnOpen. I just want to call a format method that use AJAX call to retrieve child rows data and return in after formatting as table (tr-td, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to show loading indicator in the child row, retrieve content via Ajax and inject it into the child row replacing loading indicator.

For example:

```js
// ... skipped ...

// Open this row
row.child('<p><center>Loading...</center></p>', 'no-padding' ).show();
tr.addClass('shown');
$('div.slider', row.child()).slideDown();

$.getJSON("GetStudents?id=" + id, function(data){
   $('td', row.child()).html(format(data));
   $('div.slider', row.child()).show();
});

// ... skipped ...
```

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/8rejaL88/2/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Actually I encountered a freezing problem when loading child data. Is the child record rows causing this freezing? If so, do I have to use "loading indicator"? On the other hand, is it better to use **asynchronous** in the AJAX call?

Comment: @ClintEastwood, Ajax request is asynchronous by default, that is why there is a need for loading indicator (`Loading...`). Synchronous requests may temporarily lock the browser, disabling any actions while the request is active.

Comment: There is just a little problem causing the loading indicator loops forever. I added the format code in my question. Could you please have a look at it and clarify me how to create loop properly for the multiple child records?

Comment: @ClintEastwood, there is syntax error in your updated code, instead of `'</tr>' +` should be `'</tr>';`. Check the console for errors.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is related to obtaining data parameters in the array and no error except from this. Please underestimate the tr error and just have a look at how to obtain the record values in a loop?

Comment: @ClintEastwood, you're not iterating values in the loop correctly, see https://jsfiddle.net/8rejaL88/2/

Comment: You rock!.. Thanks a lot for your kind help and efforts. This perfect answer is very useful not only for me, but also for many people who need to use master-detail jQuery DataTable. Voted+